# Explain this equality: $-90^\circ + \tan^{-1}\frac{X_C}{R} = - \tan^{-1}\frac{R}{X_C}$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$-90^\circ + \tan^{-1}\frac{X_C}{R} \;=\; - \tan^{-1}\frac{R}{X_C}$$

Please explain how both are equal.

Comment: Please type the question and paste the photo here.

Comment: \****cough***\* one cannot view such images on the school's network.  :P$${}$$\[T]'/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{Let} \ \ \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \theta$$

$$\frac{1}{x} = \tan\theta$$

$$x = \cot \theta = \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right)$$

$$\arctan x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$$

So, $$   \arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: how x=cot(theta) in step 3

Comment: @HassnainAbbas: $\cot(\theta)$ is defined as $1/\tan(\theta)$.

Comment: thank you  :) respect from Pakistan

Answer (score 0):

On a right triangle, the two angles you have described are the two non-right angles:

$$\tan \theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$$

$$\theta=\arctan\left(\dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}\right)$$

and so the identity is obvious from the sum of angles in a triangle $=180^\circ$.

Comment: EXPLANATION  please

Comment: @HassnainAbbas: I realise that English is not your first language, but you must see that "EXPLANATION please" is not very polite. In any case, this answer is already an explanation. If you don't understand it, you must tell what you don't understand.

Comment: Well i apologize for my behavior .. i just want a proof how these equations are equal ?